# Air gap for a coil calculation

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, electromagnetism, calculation

i would a help calculating the necessary air gap for a coil assuming an ideal magnetic material:
Cross sectional area of active material = 100 mm2
number of turns= 30
Inductance= 1mH

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are your calculations or references so far? Do you know that inductance is defined as flux linkage per amp for instance?

Comment: Use the reactance equation, Rcore=(MLT/(ur x u0 x Ae) Rgap=(AirGap/u0 x Ae)  L=Nturn/(Rcore +Rgap) you adjust the AirGap to meet 1mH. ur= core permeabilty and u0=air permeability (1.257* 10^-6)

Comment: If you want help we need far more information than currently provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could just plug numbers into the formula, but it's more instructive to do it from first principles. Then if you forget the exact form of the formula, you can re-derive it.

You've already suggested some numbers for turns and pole area, so let's do it for a specific airgap as well, say 1 mm. Inductance is inversely proportional to it (assuming perfect magnetic material), so it's easy to scale afterwards.

Inductance is flux linkage per amp.

1 amp in 30 turns is 30 Ampere.Turns. This produces an H field across a 1 mm airgap of 30 kA/m.

This produces a B field in the airgap of μ<sub>0</sub>H = 4π*10<sup>-7</sup> * 30k = 37.7 mT

This produces a flux of B*pole_area = 37.7m * 100μ = 3.77 μW

This produces a total flux linkage of flux*turns = 113 μW

So the inductance with a 1 mm airgap would be 113 μH.

On the face of it, all we have to do is scale down the airgap from 1 mm to 113 μm to get 1 mH. However, with an airgap this small, I doubt that we could approximate the magnetic core as ideal, and so the actual gap would need to be reduced further to allow for the finite reluctance of the core.

Comment: @csabahu Neil is right.

Comment: That's the great advantage of presenting it step by numeric step, you get peer review. I'm always losing minus signs, and powers of 10!